# Hiding multiple rows on a worksheet with different ranges

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

So I have the following code in which I'm attempting to hide rows in different set of ranges on the same sheet for which in column G the value is zero.

See the code:

```
 Sub Hide_Rows()
     Dim LR As Long, i As Long, g As Long, h As Long
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     With Sheets("PAYROLL SUMMARY")
         LR = .Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         For i = 19 To 248
             For g = 469 To 498
                 For h = 719 To 748
                    .Rows(i).Hidden = .Range("G" & i).Value = 0
                    .Rows(g).Hidden = .Range("G" & g).Value = 0
                    .Rows(h).Hidden = .Range("G" & h).Value = 0
                 Next i
             Next g
         Next h
     End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

I get the following message "Compile error:  Invalid Next control variable reference".

Any insight will be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch `Next h` and `Next i` for this code to compile:

```
         For i = 19 To 248
             For g = 469 To 498
                 For h = 719 To 748
                    .Rows(i).Hidden = .Range("G" & i).Value = 0
                    .Rows(g).Hidden = .Range("G" & g).Value = 0
                    .Rows(h).Hidden = .Range("G" & h).Value = 0
                 Next h
             Next g
         Next i
```

However, I don't understand what you are trying to do and what is the purpose of nesting loops in each other.

Also, what is the purpose of calculating variable `LR` if you don't use it in your code later?

If you just want to make the same operation for three separate ranges of data, you don't need to nest three loops in each other. You should do three separate loops like below:

```
 Sub Hide_Rows()
     Dim LR As Long, i As Long
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     With Sheets("PAYROLL SUMMARY")
        LR = .Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 19 To 248
           .Rows(i).Hidden = .Range("G" & i).Value = 0
        Next i

        For i = 469 To 498
           .Rows(i).Hidden = .Range("G" & i).Value = 0
        Next i

        For i = 719 To 748
            .Rows(i).Hidden = .Range("G" & i).Value = 0
        Next i

     End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

---

Note that for empty cells, expression `.Range("G" & i).Value = 0` also returns `True`, so all rows with empty cell in column G will be also hidden.

If you don't want to hide empty cells, use `.Text` instead of `.Value`:

```
.Rows(i).Hidden = (.Range("G" & i).Text = 0)
```